# GDB no debugging symbols found, after assembling with -g -F options

Tags: assembly, gdb, nasm

i'm very new in assembly (nasm x86_64), and i run into a problem while i tried to use gdb, which says "no debugging symbols found" after assembling with `-g -F dwarf` options.
I know that the problem can be caused by using `.txt` instead of `.text,` but i have corrected it and it didn't really help. I tried to google it, but i haven't found a solution. My `.asm` and `makefile` are on the
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgy7h.png).
P.S. sorry my poor english.

Comment: Your source and build script should be quoted as text, not shown in a screenshot.

Comment: @ecm thanks, i don't think there is a point in editing this question since it is answered already, but i'll take care of it next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your linking command
`ld ‑m elf_x86_64 ‑s $(source).o ‑o $(source)`
will *remove* the generated DWARF debugging information.
`‑s` is short for `‑‑strip‑all`.
Remove this flag for a debuggable executable.

If you wanted to keep *just* the debugging information, call [`strip(1)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strip_(Unix)) with `‑‑only‑keep‑debug` after the linking step.